# Bigquery transfer - Change date issue

Tags: google-bigquery, google-play

I am trying to edit a transfer from Google Play data, and it keeps asking me to enter a future date, regardless of how much in the future I am trying to add it.

Anyone knows any way to overcome this issue?

[image]

Comment: Issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/141234696

Comment: It is a known issue tracked with the link in Felipe's comment. Current workarounds: 
1. Create a transfer configuration from CLI/API instead of UI (preferred)
2. After selecting "Start date and run time" - switch back in "Scheduling Options" to "Start now" and then switch back to "Start at set time". Ignore "Start date and run time" error and proceed with creating transfer config

Answer (score 0):

From comments on the question, this is a known bug and possible workarounds are:

1. Create a transfer configuration from CLI/API instead of UI (preferred)
2. After selecting "Start date and run time" - switch back in "Scheduling Options" to "Start now" and then switch back to "Start at set time". Ignore "Start date and run time" error and proceed with creating transfer config --> Which I used and worked perfectly